# Does catch-all-rethrow differ in any way from having no try-catch block at all?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, rethrow

Does this code

```
try
{
    opaque_function_that_might_throw_arbitrary_exception ();
}
catch (...)
{
    throw;
}
```

differ in any way semantically from just calling

```
opaque_function_that_might_throw_arbitrary_exception ();
```

in C++? Are there differences between the standards?

I though both snippets would be semantically identical, but I checked with the compiler-explorer and it generates different code, even on the highest optimization level. This made me wonder if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Hm, I think this situation came up in a recent cppcon talk, but I'll have to check. I might have had something to do with `noexcept` or `[[noreturn]]`, and the point of termination, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a subtle difference in one particular place. Consider this main function:

```
int main() {
   RAIIHandle important_resource{ /*...*/ };

   opaque_function_that_might_throw_arbitrary_exception ();
}
```

Is `important_resource` freed upon an exception being thrwon? Well, it's implementation defined. `std::terminate` is called, but the stack may not be unwound if an exception escapes from `main`. For some resources, this could spell real trouble.

Now in this case:

```
int main() {
   try {
     RAIIHandle important_resource{ /*...*/ };
     opaque_function_that_might_throw_arbitrary_exception ();
   }
   catch(...) {
     throw;
   }
}
```

`std::terminate` is still called. But not before a suitable handler is found for the exception. The stack *must be unwound*. So our `important_resource` is definitely freed.

Comment: Interesting. Is this only true for the main function, or is this also the case for deeper stacks? In other words, assume you are, say, 5 frames down the stack and an exception is thrown, but the compiler can "prove" that there is no handler in place and the exception will escape from main. Is it possible that then no destructors are run at all; for all objects on the 5 stack frames?

Comment: @TobiasBrüll - I feel my answer may have muddled the waters for. When an exception is thrown (no matter how deep), the run time starts looking for a handler that can handle it. If the lookup can't find a handler up to and including `main`, `std::terminate` will be called. And it is unspecified if the stack, all 5 frames in your case, is unwound in that particular case. The catch-all-rethrow handler forces the unwinding in main. It will in fact force the unwinding of anything bellow it, at any scope.